# Get image dimension from url?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

How can I get the size of the image url?

I tried to use:

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
img.ImageOpened += (a, d) =>
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Width: {0}, Height: {1}", img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight);
};
Image1.Source = img;
```

but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Have you try with `img.Width` and `img.Height`?

Comment: Yes, but BitmapImage don't have Width and Height properties, only PixelWidth, PixelHeight, DecodePixelHeight and DecodePixelWidth.

Comment: Mmmm... probably because is WP's BitmapImage...

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean "it dot not solve my problem"? The dimensions are wrong or empty?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy. Yes it WinRT BitmapImage. I get a null value

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the `ImageOpened` event of the `Image` control instead:

```
<Image x:Name="Image1" ImageOpened="Image1_OnImageOpened" ></Image>
```

and get the width and the height in the handler

```
private void Image1_OnImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var width =(Image1.Source as BitmapImage).PixelWidth;
    var height =(Image1.Source as BitmapImage).PixelHeight;
}
```